# Series $\sum \lambda^{n-k} c_k $ converges to zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Let $(c_n)$ a sequence of real number, such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n=0$, Let $0<\lambda<1 $ and  $\lambda^nc_0+\lambda^{n-1}c_1+\cdots+\lambda c_{n-1}+c_n=y_n$ a sequence.

I have to prove that sequence converges to zero. 
For that, we observe exist a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$, such that, $|c_{n_0}|<\varepsilon$ for any $n>n_0$. So, we split the partial sum in two:
$$|y_n| = |(\lambda^nc_0+\lambda^{n-1}c_1+\cdots+\lambda^{n-n_0} c_{n_0})+(\lambda^{n-n_0-1}c_{n_0+1}+\lambda^{n-n_0-2}c_1+\cdots+\lambda c_{n-1}+c_n)|$$

$$|y_n| \leq |\lambda^nc_0+\lambda^{n-1}c_1+\cdots+\lambda^{n-n_0} c_{n_0}|+|\lambda^{n-n_0-1}c_{n_0+1}+\lambda^{n-n_0-2}c_1+\cdots+\lambda c_{n-1}+c_{n}|$$
$$|y_n| \leq |\lambda^nc_0+\lambda^{n-1}c_1+\cdots+\lambda^{n-n_0} c_{n_0}|+\varepsilon|\lambda^{n-n_0-1}+\lambda^{n-n_0-2}+\cdots+\lambda +1|$$
$$|y_n| \leq |\lambda^nc_0+\lambda^{n-1}c_1+\cdots+\lambda^{n-n_0} c_{n_0}|+\varepsilon\left|\frac{\lambda^{n-n_0-1}-1}{\lambda-1}\right|$$

The left term of sum goes to cero as $n \to \infty$, How can I choose the epsilon to make the right term converge to zero as $n\to \infty$?

Comment: Unless $\lvert \lambda\rvert<1$, the claim is false.

Comment: Yes, I missed, I'm gonna fix it

Comment: Think of the last inequality as the following: For a given $\epsilon>0$, and $n_0$ chosen as you did (depending on $\epsilon$), the inequality holds for all $n\geq n_0$. For fixed $\epsilon$ and $n_0$, the right-hand side goes to $\frac{\epsilon}{1-\lambda}$ as $n\to\infty$, so it is smaller than $\frac{2\epsilon}{1-\lambda}$ for all $n$ sufficiently large. This shows that for every $\epsilon$ there exists $N$ such that $|y_n|<\frac{2\epsilon}{1-\lambda}$ whenever $n\geq N$. So use $\epsilon'=\epsilon(1-\lambda)/2$ instead of $\epsilon$.